# Android Nougat limits network connection when app in foreground

Tags: android, xamarin, websocket

I'm developing Android app with background service. Service is running in its own process (like `com.example.app:extProccess`). Service creating WebSockets connection. But after less than 1 min after service started there is a disconnection on WebSockets, but service is alive (not killed by Android). After 20-30 min a connection is recovering.

Seem like device entered in Doze, but very soon. 
This is observed only on some Nougat devices.

If I prevent battery optimization (`android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`) for this app service and websockets working correctly without disconnects.

My question is why Android limits network so quickly if my app in foreground? So how to hold networking for background service in this case without using `android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`?

Comment: You can try a WakeLock around the Read/write/... calls, this (partially) helped for me

Comment: I have this code in `OnCreate` in my service:
`PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            wakeLock = mgr.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial | WakeLockFlags.AcquireCausesWakeup, "MyWakeLock");
            wakeLock.Acquire();`

Comment: Maintaining an active network connection is a very high battery cost, one way to do this going forward is to defeat the OS's battery optimizations like you are doing, another way is to do a foreground service, .... ***Ideally***, you need to disconnect/close your socket upon entering background mode and start up push notifications in order to keep the app up to date (or use the new job schedule features) and upon entering the foreground, establish your realtime web socket again.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Android API 21(Lollipop), Google started giving more focus on battery optimisations. The problem comes is any service. One way to overcome this is to use Job Schedulers for your background tasks(documentation available [here](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html)). Also, any task that uses android resources a lot will be terminated by the Android Framework. The only solution for your particular use case is to either optimise your code or use "IGNORE BATTERY OPTIMISATIONS" as done by you.